# Show toolbar and bottom navigation view again

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-toolbar, bottomnavigationview

I have implemented show and hide functionality for toolbar and bottomNavigationView while scrolling up and down in recyclerView. 
Now i click on recyclerView item and go to detail page which does not have recyclerView, now also toolbar and bottomNavigationView are hidden. Any method to make them visible again in this fragment.

main_activity.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    />


<com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@drawable/menu_view"
    android:isScrollContainer="false"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_item_color_state"
    app:menu="@menu/my_navigation_items" />
```

BottomNavigationViewBehaviour.java

```
public class BottomNavigationViewBehavior extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<BottomNavigationView> {

private int height;

@Override
public boolean onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout parent, BottomNavigationView child, int layoutDirection) {
    height = child.getHeight();
    return super.onLayoutChild(parent, child, layoutDirection);
}

@Override
public boolean onStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, BottomNavigationView child,
                                   View directTargetChild, View target, int nestedScrollAxes) {
    return nestedScrollAxes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL;
}

@Override
public void onNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, BottomNavigationView child, View target,
                           int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed) {
    if (dyConsumed > 0) {
        slideDown(child);
    } else if (dyConsumed < 0) {
        slideUp(child);
    }
}

private void slideUp(BottomNavigationView child) {
    child.clearAnimation();
    child.animate().translationY(0).setDuration(50);
}

private void slideDown(BottomNavigationView child) {
    child.clearAnimation();
    child.animate().translationY(height).setDuration(50);
}
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) mBottomNav.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.setBehavior(new BottomNavigationViewBehavior());
    mBottomNav.clearAnimation();
    mBottomNav.animate().translationY(mBottomNav.getHeight()).setDuration(100);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use AppbarLayout to expand using appbarLayout.setExpand(true) but this only show your action bar not your bottomNavigationbar.

Comment: Thanks! :) This helps in fixing appbar but not bottomnavigationview. Any solution for that ?